# Token offset sql error NHIBERNATE

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I have this table:

TABLE "Set": [PK:IdSet (int), IdProject (int),IdSetState(int),IdPriority(int),NumSet(int),Unit(nchar),NumDisc(int)]

And using NUnit testing.

this is my test method:

```
[Test]
        public void Can_add_Set()
        {
            var set = new Set { IdProject = 2, IdSetState = 2, NumDisc = 1, IdPriority = 3, NumSet = 100};
            setRepository.AddSet(set);
        }
```

this is my method for insert a Set:

```
public void AddSet(Set set) 
        {
            using (ISession session = NHibernateSessionBuilder.OpenSession())
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(set);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
```

This is the mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="AdminProject"
                   namespace="AdminProject.Business.Entity">

  <class name="Set">
    <id name="IdSet">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="IdProject" />
    <property name="IdSetState" />
    <property name="IdPriority" />
    <property name="Unit" />
    <property name="NumDisc" />
    <property name="NumSet" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

when the session.save(set); occurs this error:

"User code not control SqlCeException"

"Failed to parse the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 13,Token in error = Set ]"

How can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't set a reserved keyword? Try qualifying it with "" or []

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="AdminProject"
                   namespace="AdminProject.Business.Entity">

  <class name="[Set]">
    <id name="IdSet">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="IdProject" />
    <property name="IdSetState" />
    <property name="IdPriority" />
    <property name="Unit" />
    <property name="NumDisc" />
    <property name="NumSet" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

SQL CE reserved keywords:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258313(v=sql.80).aspx